# Rotate video preview in Matlab

Tags: matlab, stream, rotation, preview

In Matlab I can get a preview from a camera with the command:
`preview(obj,himage)` that puts the preview stream into himage.

In my code I have an axes that contains the video preview but I would like to rotate the video by 90 degrees.
This might be very stupid but I cannot figure out how is done.

My code is the following:

```
prevHaxes = axes('Parent', mainFig);

previewImage= imagesc(placeholderImg,'Parent', prevHaxes); %Placeholder for when the stream is off

preview(video_obj, previewImage);
```

I have tried to use imrotate but I got the following error:

```
Expected input number 1, input image, to be one of these types:

numeric, logical

Instead its type was matlab.graphics.primitive.Image.
```

So my question is, is there a way to get the video preview from a camera but to visualize it rotated by an angle?